# How to Traverse a next pages using SgmlLinkextractor in Scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I Cannot traverse next page, a bit stuck with Rule of SgmlLinkextractor.
Please navigate me further, i don't know where i made mistake

```
import scrapy
from product.items import ProductItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor


class BurlingtoncoatfactoryDSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "burlingtoncoatfactory_d"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.burlingtoncoatfactory.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.burlingtoncoatfactory.com/catalog/searchresults.aspx?filter=&search=south+shore+furnitures&viewMode=FortyEight#pg=1']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('catalog/searchresults\.aspx\?filter=&search=south+shore+furnitures&viewMode=FortyEight#pg=\d*',),),
             callback='parse', follow= True),

        )


    def parse(self, response):
        item=ProductItem()
        item['product_DetailUrl'] = [content for content in   response.xpath('//div[@id="hawkitemlist"]//div[@class="row clearfix"]//div[@class="product-image"]/a/@href').extract()]
        item['product_Rating'] = [content for content in response.xpath('//*//div[@class="product-inner clearfix"]/div[@class="review"]/span[1]/@class').extract()] 
        item['product_NumberOfReviews'] = [content for content in response.xpath('//*//div[@class="product-inner clearfix"]/div[@class="review"]/span[2]/text()').extract()] 
        yield item
```

Comment: It looks like next pages are loaded through JavaScript. If you click the "next" arrow on that sample page in your `start_urls`, you can see an XHR call to http://www.burlingtoncoatfactory.com/HawkSearch/HawkSearchProxy.aspx?filter=&search=south+shore+furnitures&viewMode=FortyEight&pg=2&ajax=1&json=1 . This is probably what you need to fetch (it returns JSON data). Note that `allowed_domains` should list domains, not URL, so use `allowed_domains = ["burlingtoncoatfactory.com"]`

Comment: got it..Thanks for your answer.